# Two-fingered right click on iBook G4 OS X Tiger PPC

Tags: trackpad, powerpc, macos

I have a PPC iBook G4 and really would like to be able to have the two-fingered click to secondary-click functionality. I did a lot of googling, but nothing really came up, mostly stuff for other versions of OS X and for the Intel iBooks, not PPC.

I did eventually come across iScroll 2, http://iscroll2.sourceforge.net, but that says it is incompatible with my trackpad :(.

Does anyone know of any other ways I can add the two-finger click functionality?

Comment: ... and what version of OS X is it?

Comment: @CEdgar I mentioned it in the title, OS X Tiger (10.4.11).

Answer (score 1):

Your computer isn't supported, I'm sorry. I have the same computer as you and I've spent hours searching but nothing exists if your computer does not have compatible trackpad drivers. Ask Apple about getting some new trackpad drivers installed via Live Chat or phone.